# asp.net core - How to get the [Authorize(Policy = "PolicyName")] or other property from all controllers

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I would like to get the attribute for "[Authorize(Policy" from all controllers and put it into a List.  I have tried a few ways and searched with no success.  I don't have any examples that I have tried to post.  I have tried a few different reflection ways but no luck.

Thanks.
Francisco

Comment: This gets me closer;

Comment: var attribs = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                .ToList()
                .Select(
                d =>
                    d.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>() )
                    .ToList();

Comment: From here:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465436/how-to-get-custom-attributes-for-a-controller-in-asp-net-core-rc2)